# Wrong questions and wrong answers

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, moderation, answers

What if someone posts an answer which, in fact, doesn't answer the question? What if, in addition, it is claimed in the answer that the question "is wrong"? Are there any moderating rules regarding such answers?

Comment: This would be a better question if you referred to the question and answer in question.

Comment: @Dave: I believe it is related to this question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7559/the-average-number-of-annual-publications-for-cs-postdocs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally wrong answers should be down-voted. You can comment on the question and hope that the poster edits or deletes the answer. This could lead to a comment-debate, which will eventually be drawn to the moderators' attention, and we can decide whether to do something about it. If the answer adds nothing to the discussion, a moderator may delete it.

Another option is to flag the answer for moderator attention, but this won't necessarily mean that it will be deleted. If it truly doesn't answer the question, this might result in a moderator down-voting the answer.

In any case, if it does not answer the question, you can (implicitly) indicate this by not accepting the answer.

Comment: (1) “If it truly doesn't answer the question, this might result in a moderator down-voting the question.”  I think that you meant “… down-voting the answer.”  (2) I do not comment on whether moderators should do anything in the particular instance which Leo is talking about.

Comment: Thanks for (1). Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

On the question at hand, I actually think the answer, if not what you're looking for, is definitely within scope for the question. Since you disagree, your best option is to downvote it, and not accept it. I don't think any further action is warranted.

Answer (score 4):

Jeff's answer may not be the answer you are looking for but it doesn't mean that it is not an answer, I personally think it is a good answer to the question.

You are free to choose to accept whichever answer you like most, and you can vote on answers as you please. Other users are also free to post answers and vote as they please. Looking at the votes, it seems that other users think that Jeff's answer is a good one. You cannot restrict the answers to those answers you like.

If you don't like the answers you have got so far then check this FAQ entry: [What if I don’t get a good answer?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty)

Answer (score 4):

If you ask a question and see no answers you like, one course of action is to [put a bounty](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) on the question.  You can even specify in the comments the type of answer you think would get awarded the bounty.  This would incentivize people to answer the questions your way, as you'd be the one to determine who gets the bounty.

One note: you need at least 75 reputation to offer a bounty.